# Sql Server replication - add articles without using wizard

Tags: sql-server, replication, database-replication, transactional-replication

I have done transnational replication to my SQL Server 2014 instance.

There are two db servers subscribing to it. Currently I have added 
only some of the tables (10 tables) as articles to replicate. However, in the future there will be new tables added to the distributor database that needs to be included as replication articles.

I know that whenever I want to add a new article to the replication, I can go to the Properties of publication and add new articles through the wizard.

However, my problem is that there are some tables added by an application through T-SQL queries.Those tables need to be replicated. So there is no way
I can go to the wizard and add those to articles.

Is there a way that I can add articles to the replication through a T-SQL? or Is there any system stored procedure or anything we can use to add articles to replication.

Comment: _Is there a way that I can add articles to the replication through a T-SQL? or Is there any system stored procedure or anything we can use to add articles to replication_ Yes. If you google you will find it.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I did. But I could not find any useful resource.

Comment: You can use the script button in the wizard to script out all the T-SQL required. You can adjust that as required